# Fetch TaskID or InstanceID of a running instance in Camunda 8.2

Tags: camunda

Can you please guide me if there is any API in Camunda 8.2 that would return me the current `TaskID` or `ProcessInstanceID` of a running instance? I have a unique variable within the process. I am hoping I could query using the variable name and value, if possible. Or any other way of identifying the `ProcessInstanceID` from within the running instance.

Answer (score 0):

In Camunda 7, You can call the [GetTasks](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/task/get-query/) to find the task by passing the **processVariables** parameter and then from the response extract the associated Id. In Camunda 8 API, I think the [search tasks](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-tools/tasklist-api-rest/controllers/tasklist-api-rest-task-controller/#search-tasks) is your answer.